# Rhel 7 not booting up

Tags: rhel, x11, xorg, gnome

I recently installed rhel 7 on my laptop as dual boot (with windows 8.1) in UEFI mode. After the installation I cannot log into redhat.  The gnome desktop starts to load and then it goes to a black screen with an underscore at top left corner. No key works at this stage except the power button.
My laptop is dell inspiron 15r 5537, 4th gen i5, 8gb ram amd graphics card.
I had this same screen while trying to install rhel (while booting from dvd in uefi). After some reboots the anaconda installer just started. 
And I installed rhel server with gui.
What is the issue?

Comment: Did you use this the proper live cd?

Comment: Yes. I reinstalled the os with 'minimal installation' then installed the gnome desktop . It was working fine. But then i installed amd catalyst for rhel and then the gnome failed again.

Comment: Can you post the output of: `lshw -C display`?

Comment: I bet for RAM issue: can you run a check? (i.e. memtest86 is a tool)

Comment: It seems that your graphics card might be the issue. My assumption is that your laptop has an NVIDIA graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

I have a RHEL 7 laptop with 2 external Full HD monitors.  Even though the laptop lid was closed the GNOME was displaying on it.  I got half a clue when I <ctrl>+<F2> and was able to log in on the external monitors which were now operating in mirror mode. I confirmed GNOME was running and had no errors, I just could not see it....until I lifted the lid on the laptop. With RHEL 6 I could not have 3 screens, with RHEL 7 I can, free upgrade!

I hope your issue is as simple as mine.
KDE Plasma works a treat and keeps my laptop a lot cooler than GNOME3:
yum groupinstall kde-desktop-environment

Select Plasma at the login screen by clicking the cog/gear icon.